# How banking application logout if user submit valid URL from address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to logout an user if he/she tries to submit any valid URL from the address bar?

I tried jQuery on items below but it is not working.

1. `window.location.href`
2. `window.unload`

#### unload code

```
    (window).unload(
       function(event) {
       //code to handle
     });
```

#### location href code

```
     (function() //create a scope so 'location' is not global
        { var location = window.location.href;
          setInterval(function()
          {
            if(location != window.location.href)
            {
              location = window.location.href;
              window.location.changed(location);
            }
          }, 1000);
        }
      )();
      window.location.changed = function(e)
      {        console.log(e);//outputs http://newhref.com
        //this is fired when the window changes location
      }
```

Comment: Javascript can't take action when the user tries to navigate away from the page, this would be a security violation. This is how adware used to prevent people from closing the page. Use a timeout on sessions.

Comment: How did you "try jQuery on below items" ? What did you do with them? Show us.

Comment: @Rudie added both code in description

Comment: [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: @LJᛃ In between other alternative. Will update once I check onbeforeunload.

Comment: @LJᛃ I checked onbeforeunload. This event get executed even on click of URL. There is no way to capture button click of navigation box. It is not helpful in this scenario.